# Deletion notice for my Google Cloud Shell home directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I got a deletion notice for my Google Cloud Shell home directory. Does that mean that my data will also be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits):

> If you do not access Cloud Shell for 120 days, we will delete your
>   home disk. You will receive an email notification before we do so and
>   simply starting a session will prevent its removal.

This only applies to the home directory of your Cloud Shell instance (you may want to store it on Cloud Storage anyway if you want to keep it). Any other Google services you use will be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Considering i'm paying for their services this is extremely annoying. Lost a lot of important documents and feel like taking my business somewhere else.